# R- Highest Standard deviation/Variance of a column based on entries in another column

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I am using a dataframe which has multiple columns, where I want to calculate the highest variance or standard deviation of column 1 as a function of entries in column 2.
For example, if my data set looks like below, I want to calculate highest standard deviation for School A, School B and School C separately.

```
School City Percent
A       X     92
B       Y     80
C       Z     95
A       X     89
B       Y     75
```

Comment: How are we supposed to calculate a variance for schools with only one or two instances? Furthermore asking for a variance of "column 1" from that dataset is just nonsense.

Comment: The actual data set is huge. This was just an example to explain my question.

Comment: If one of these answers helped you solve your problem please select it as correct by checking the green checkbox next to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, the function `ave()` can be used to add a column with a quantity derived from other columns according to different groups in the data.frame.

Here is an example:

```
df1$var <- with(df1, ave(Percent, School, FUN=var))
df1$sd <- with(df1, ave(Percent, School, FUN=sd))
> df1
#  School City Percent  var       sd
#1      A    X      92  4.5 2.121320
#2      B    Y      80 12.5 3.535534
#3      C    Z      95   NA       NA
#4      A    X      89  4.5 2.121320
#5      B    Y      75 12.5 3.535534
```

The entry with the largest value can be extracted using `which.max()`:

```
df1[which.max(df1$var),]
#  School City Percent  var       sd
#2      B    Y      80 12.5 3.535534
```

---

Another base R option is to use `aggregate()`. This will represent the results in a more compact form:

```
df2 <- setNames(aggregate(Percent~School, df1, var), c("School", "Percent.var"))
> df2
#  School Percent.var
#1      A         4.5
#2      B        12.5
#3      C          NA
```

and

```
df2 <- setNames(aggregate(Percent~School, df1, sd), c("School", "Percent.sd"))
> df2
#  School Percent.sd
#1      A   2.121320
#2      B   3.535534
#3      C         NA
```

Or, both `aggregate` operations combined:

```
df2 <- setNames(do.call(data.frame,
                aggregate(Percent~School, df1, function(x) c(var(x),sd(x)))),
                c("School","Percent.var","Percent.sd"))
#  School Percent.var Percent.sd
#1      A         4.5   2.121320
#2      B        12.5   3.535534
#3      C          NA         NA
```

In these cases, too, the maximum value can be extracted from the output by using `which.max()`:

```
df2[which.max(df2$Percent.sd),]
#  School Percent.var Percent.sd
#2      B        12.5   3.535534
```

**data used in this example:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(School = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
                 .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                 City = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
                 .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
                 Percent = c(92L, 80L, 95L, 89L, 75L)), 
                 .Names = c("School", "City", "Percent"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate the standard deviation for each school (A,B,C) seperately

```
df<-data.frame(school=c("A","B","C","A","B"),percent=c(92,80,95,89,75))

library(dplyr)
result<-split(df,df$school)%>%lapply(.,function(x)sd(x$percent))%>%unlist(.)%>%as.data.frame(.)
res<-cbind(row.names(result),result)
colnames(res)<-c("school","std_dev")
res


#output
> res
  school  std_dev
A      A 2.121320
B      B 3.535534
C      C       NA
```